# Why doesn't julia support something like switch-case

Tags: julia

Julia doesn't support something like a **switch-case a control structure**, at least according to the current documentation of **Control Flow**?

**switch case** is a common **Flow Control** in imperative or object oriented languages, why not in julia?

Language supporting switch-case (not completed)

- C/C++
- Java
- Pascal
- PHP
- Javascript
- Typescript
- Octave

Answer (score 16):

The basic philosophy of julia is to provide most functionality as packages and keep the core (Base) ultra-lean. So the answer to "why doesn't Julia support X" is usually "Julia supports X via package Y". In this case, the Match.jl provides a switch-case like structure that is very powerful.
There is also a Switch.jl package that is very close to C's switch, but it is not actively maintained.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention match.jl!

Comment: This is very much a big problem with julia specifically though. Other languages or enviornments where such functionality is delegated to external packages, have appropriate facilities to conduct appropriate searches on the package database. Julia does not. At best you can try to [Ctrl]+F on the `pkg.julialang.org` website, but as this particular example shows, you'd only find the unmaintained `Switch` pkg, and not the appropriate `Match` package instead. With julia, the only reliable way to find if such functionality exists in a package is to do exactly what OP did: ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's a good point, why not open an issue on https://github.com/JuliaCI/pkg.julialang.org ?

Comment: add to that the fact that `apropos` is only as good as the helpstrings, and julia has notoriously poor helpstring documentation, and you have a recipe for disaster. until such usability issues are addressed, julia has a long way to go before v1.0

Comment: I did a while ago (in a similar form). The issue has been raised (and generally agreed upon but otherwise largely ignored) many times in some form or another.

Comment: e.g. here's the post I made a while back: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/20339

Comment: Yeah, we actually do something like what you suggest in that issue in Plots

Comment: But actually reading that issue, Stefan promises you that this feature will be in Pkg3, which is close now. So it seems a bit unfair to say it is largely ignored.

Comment: Can you add a shoutout to [CSyntax.jl](https://github.com/Gnimuc/CSyntax.jl#cswitch) package? It includes a `CSwitch` module which is the spiritual successor to `Switch.jl` and works with modern Julia (v1.8 at time of this comment). In particular, `CSwitch` supports fall-through case statements which the other solutions out there (eg, `Match.jl`) do not.

Answer (score 9):

There is extensive discussion about including this in julia language. It will probably happen at some point but maybe not until after v1.0.

See here for the main discussion (includes links to other discussions): https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18285

& this one is informative too (but now closed in favour of the above):
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5410

#### edit

Also it is worth mentioning that julia need not offer *syntax* for switch-case because it might be best (in terms of features) to have it implemented as a *macro* (i.e. via metaprogramming) which need not be included in Base julia.